# Is there way to convert string "1+2-3" to a result 0

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, algorithm, integer

I've got a string `'1plus2minus3'` and I could convert it into string `'1+2-3'`.

Is there a way to calculate the result by converting this `str()` to `int()`?

Comment: If the string comes from user input, do **not** use `eval` which I'm sure will be suggested in the answers

Answer (score 3):

There are answers already with `eval()`, but here is another one, using `re` module, which is safer:

```
s = '1+2-3'

import re

result = sum(map(int, re.findall(r'[+-]?\d+', s)))
print(result)
```

Prints:

```
0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the folling steps:

1. Replace the string `plus` with `+` and `minus` with `-`.
2. Use `eval()`. `eval('1+2-3')` will result in `0`.

Comment: Thank you! That was I searching for

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution is

```
eval('1+2-3') == 0
```